# How to create dynamic header with vertical table in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have data:

```
data = 
    [
       {
          "name":"bolb",
          "category_name":"Electronics",
          "size":"34",
          "price":"890",
          "currency_name":"Us",
       },
       {
          "name":"bolb",
          "category_name":"Electronics",
          "size":"2",
          "price":"9099",
          "currency_name":"Us",
       }
    ]
```

I need to show this data into template like as below.

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Category Compare</td>
    <td>bolb</td>
    <td>bolb asun</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>price </td>
    <td>890</td>
    <td>9099</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>category_name</td>
    <td>Electronics</td>
    <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>currency_name</td>
        <td>Us</td>
        <td>Us</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

My desire output table vertically with dynamic. I have added image also for clarification. Can i change my variable data or i can do it using for loop.Please suggest best idea or code will be appreciate.
This is my output image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Category Compare</td>
            {% for i in data %}
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>price </td>
            {% for i in data %}
                <td>{{i.price}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>category_name</td>
            {% for i in data %}
                <td>{{i.category_name}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>currency_name</td>
            {% for i in data %}
                <td>{{i.currency_name}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```